# Taylor-polynomial of function $f(x) = e^{x}*\sin(2x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

*This is not homework, I'm asking to learn for an exam which I'll write in 2.5 months.*

> Count the Taylor-polynomial 3th grade of the function $f: \mathbb{R}
> \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) = e^{x}\sin(2x)$ in $x_{0} = 0$

3th grade means we will need the derivations $0,1,2,3$ of $f$:
$$\begin{align}
&f^{(0)}(x) = e^{x}\sin(2x)\\
&f^{(1)}(x) = e^{x}(\sin(2x)+2\cos(2x))\\
&f^{(2)}(x) = e^{x}(-3\sin(2x)+4\cos(2x))\\
&f^{(3)}(x) = e^{x}(-11\sin(2x)-2\cos(2x))
\end{align}$$
which implies
$$\begin{align}
e^{x}\sin(2x) &= \frac{f^{0}(0)}{0!}(x-0)^{0}+\frac{f^{1}(0)}{1!}(x-0)^{1}+\frac{f^{2}(0)}{2!}(x-0)^{2}+\frac{f^{3}(0)}{3!}(x-0)^{3}+\cdots\\
&= \frac{0}{1}\cdot 1+ \frac{2}{1}x + \frac{4}{2}x^2 - \frac{2}{6}x^{3}+\cdots\\
&= 2x +2x^{2}- \frac{x^{3}}{3}+\cdots
\end{align}$$

Now my questions:

1) Did I do it correctly?

2) If it says 3rd grade in the task, am I only allowed to derivate 3 times then?

3) How can I create the series in the end with $2x +2x^{2}- \frac{x^{3}}{3}+\cdots$ if there is much info missing (without more derivations, I cannot see what will come next and thus I cannot create the complete series. BUT the task only said 3th grade, so it should have been enough, no?

Comment: don't use $\ast $ for the multiplication, write $e^x \sin(2x)$ instead

Comment: You could also calculate $\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}6\right)\cdot\left(2x-\frac{8x^3}{6}\right)$ and skip all terms that turn out to be $x^4$ and higher.

Comment: You can also use $2\sin x= e^{ix}-e^{-ix}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, you have a mistake, this is how things should be: $$f'(0)=2 \quad \text{and} \quad f''(0)=4$$

$\textbf{Another way to proceed}$: if you know the series expansion of  both $e^x$ and $\sin(2x)$:
$$e^x=1+x+\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {x^3}6+\cdots$$
$$\sin(2x)=2x-\frac {4x^3}3+\cdots$$

Then $$e^x\sin(2x)=\left(1+x+\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {x^3}6+\cdots\right)\left(2x-\frac {4x^3}3+\cdots\right)$$
$$=2x-\frac {4x^3}3+2x^2-\frac{4x^4}3+{x^3}-\frac{4x^5}6+\cdots$$
$$=2x+2x^2-\frac13x^3+\cdots$$

$\textbf{If you want to find the general expression}:$

We're only interested in the coefficient of the $\cos(2x)$ in the $n^{th}$ derivative so let $a(n)$ be that coefficient and $b(n)$ the coefficient of $\sin(2x)$. We notice that if $g^{(n)}(x)=e^xf(x)$ then $g^{(n+1)}(x)=e^x(f(x)+f'(x))$ this implies that the coefficients in the $(n+1)^{st}$ derivative  are related to those of the previous as follows:
$$a(n+1)=a(n)+2b(n)$$$$b(n+1)=b(n)-2a(n)$$

If we multiply the second equation by two, then subtract it from the first, we get:
$$a(n+1)-2b(n+1)=5a(n)$$
or $$a(n)-2b(n)=5a(n-1)$$

Replacing $2b(n)$ in the first equation yields $$a(n+1)=2a(n)-5a(n-1)$$
with $a(0)=0$ and $a(1)=2$. This is a way of generating each coefficient in the Taylor series. Solving the recurrence relation using the characteristic equation results in:
$$a(n)=\frac 12i((1-2i)^n-(1+2i)^n)$$
So that generally $$\color{blue}{\boxed{\quad e^x\sin(2x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 12i((1-2i)^k-(1+2i)^k)\frac{x^k}{k!}\quad}}$$

But honestly, I don't think they were asking for this general solution.

Comment: Thanks, just realized and corrected that :)
But what comes now? I don't need to make this sum symbol?
I'm finished now?

Comment: @cnmesr Since it says "3rd grade" then you should stop here I suppose

Comment: Alright.
No need to make sum symbol for the end result?

Comment: @cnmesr I have found the general form of the Taylor expansion, but I don't think they asked for it...

Comment: Ouch this is so complicated and time consuming, and it's one of many tasks in the exam (120 min!).
But you are saying that this wasn't asked, right?

Comment: @cnmesr No, it is not asked! do not worry...

Comment: Thank you so much GeorgSaliba!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You miscalculated the first and second order terms, remember that $sin(0) = 0$ and $ cos(0) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your work above $f''(0) = 4$  check this.

Where did the $x^1$ term go?

$f(x) = \frac {0}{0!} + \frac {2}{1!}x + \frac {4}{2!}x^2 + \frac {-2}{3!} x^3 \cdots$

I would say $3^{rd}$ degree polynomial, and not "grade."  But that would be correct, the highest exponent of $x = 3.$  And, the highest derivative you would need is 3.

What about the remaining terms of the polynomial?
If $x$ is small, then $x^2$ is smaller and the higher degree terms are smaller than that.  Depending on the size of your interval, the higher degrees of the polynomial are irrelevant.

Or, more precisely, we can find a bound for the error, and decide if our estimate is sufficiently precise for our needs.